# the setTimout() function doesnt work inside function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So, here is function, when I put `setTimeout()` function in the `checkForm` function it doesnt work, also tried putting it outside `checkForm` function and it also doesnt work.

```
function checkForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('user-email').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    var error = "";

    if (name.length == 1 || email.length == 1 || message.length == 1) {
        error = "Min length of the fields is 2 character."
    } else if (name == "" || email == "" || message == "") {
        error = "Fields are empty."
    } else if (name.length > 15 || email.length > 20 || message.length > 100) {
        error = "Max length of the fields is 15 charcaters."
    }

    if (error == "") {
        alert("You sucessfully filled up the form.");
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "https://www.ebay.com/"
        }, 5000);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: "it doesn't work' is not a good description of the problem.  Please read our [ask] page and come back to improve this question.

Comment: so this function is a form which gets username, email and message from user and it checks it with if statements and then it checks the form so if there is no errors and everything is good it creating the alert with message and then i tried putting setTimeout() function to redirect the user to ebay page(for ex.) after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You try this way

```
setTimeout(function () {
  location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_href_set";
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change to `window.location.href = "your link"`

```js
function checkForm(event) {
    
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "https://www.ebay.com/";
            alert('go to ebay');
        }, 2000);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkForm()">Check Form</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By any chance  is the alert popping up and you are not acknowledging the pop-up and this is causing the browser to wait for you to acknowledge the pop up. if that is the case remove the alert("You sucessfully filled up the form.") and check if it works